# CoreData batch sync on startup relationships not saving

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I start off with this in AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    CoreDataManager.shared.managedContext = self.persistentContainer.viewContext
    CoreDataManager.shared.model = self.persistentContainer.managedObjectModel

    SessionManager.shared.getCountries(completion: {
        SessionManager.shared.getStates(completion: {
            CoreDataManager.shared.updateCountryStateRelationships()
            CoreDataManager.shared.save()
        })
    })

    return true
}
```

Then those methods finally end up here...

```
struct CoreDataManager {

    var countryCache = [String : NSManagedObjectID()

    func addCountry(name: String) {

        var country = insertEntity(with: "Country") as? Country
        country?.name = name
        ...
        ...

        countryCache[code] = country!.objectID
    }

    func addState(name: String) {

        var state = insertEntity(with: "State") as? State
        state?.name = name
        ...
        ...
    }

    func updateCountryStateRelationships() {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "State")
        let states = getAllManagedObjects(fetchRequest: fetchRequest) as! [State]
        for state in states {
            if let countryID = countryCache[state.countryCode!],
            let country = managedContext.object(with: countryID) as? Country {
                state.country = country
                country.addToStates(state)
            }
        }
    }
```

All the countries are fetched, and each one inserted in the context.  Each countries managed object id is saved in the cache dictionary.  When all countries have been added the context is saved.

All the states are fetched, and each one inserted in the context.  When all states have been added the context is saved.

Then the relationships are created, each country can have many states and a state has one country.

The countries and states save fine, the relationships look like they are created properly, but then when save is called at the end, I get a core data error.

`NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.), NSValidationErrorKey=country, NSValidationErrorShouldAttemptRecoveryKey=true}`

Which upon researching seems to indicate that I haven't satisfied the relationship properly when saving?  That a non-optional core data property is nil?  But when I use breakpoints on the relationship, it seems everything is set fine and nothing ends up nil.

Please let me know if you have any insight.  Much appreciated!

Comment: let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<State>(entityName: "State")

Comment: @SachinVas Thanks, but that doesn't build. `Cannot convert value of type 'NSFetchRequest<State>' to expected argument type 'NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>?`  Also I cast `states` as `[State]` anyway so not sure how it would help.

Comment: let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<State> = State.fetchRequest()